# SVN Incremental backup

Tags: backup, svn

I have few remote SVN Repos and I would like to get them backup in a incremental way.

could somebody can help me , thank you ?

Comment: what do you mean by incremental way ?

Comment: everytime not the total backup , i just want the changes .

Answer (score 1):

This [SVN dump incremental using revision number](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) may help you

Comment: Thank you for answering +1 ,but I want the description also. I want some practical answers with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use backup tools... It doesn't matter you have remove repository. You can checkout it with svn (checkout is incremental) and then run any backup tool you want to against your local copy. If you can run backups from the server hosting your repositories, that's even better.

For backup tools, check [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem).

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls /export/subversion); do

  j=$(echo $i | sed -e "s/\.//g")

  if [ "$i" = "$j" ]; then
   if [ ! -d /export/backup/subversion/$i ]; then svnadmin create /export/backup/subversion/$i; fi

   locnum=$(/usr/bin/svnlook youngest /export/subversion/$i)
   remnum=$(/usr/bin/svnlook youngest /export/backup/subversion/$i)
   newnum=$(($remnum + 1))

   if [ "$locnum" -eq "$remnum" ]; then
       echo $i $locnum-$remnum;
   else
       echo $i $locnum-$newnum-$remnum
       if [ "$locnum" -ge "$remnum" ]; then
          if [ "$remnum" -eq 0 ]; then
               svnadmin dump /export/subversion/$i | svnadmin load -q --bypass-prop-validation --force-uuid /export/backup/subversion/$i
          else
               svnadmin dump /export/subversion/$i --incremental -r $newnum:$locnum | svnadmin load -q --bypass-prop-validation /export/backup/subversion/$i
          fi
       fi
   fi
  fi
done
```